# Qt QImage - check sprites collide

Tags: qt, sprite, game-engine, qpainter, qimage

I have 2 sprites (QImage) = two pictures with transparent backgrounds. I want to know if sprites collide.
I already check if two rectangles overlap. But I want to know if the two images really overlap (red zone).

[image]

My first thought was to create an image where the two images overlap (pink rectangle) using QPainter and QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceIn or QPainter::CompositionMode_DestinationIn. This way if the images are trully overlapping the new image will not be entirely transparent.
But how to check if it is completely transparent in a fast way?

How can I check if two images really overlap in a very fast way?
What is your approach?

Comment: Can I ask how big the sprites are?  If they're small enough (32x32 for example) then the approach you suggest should work fine by simply scanning the composite image data returned by `QImage::constBits`.  And you'll only need to perform that check iff the bounding rectangles intersect.

Comment: The size of sprites is the user choice. So images can be large or small.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't wrong. The composite image can be a bitmap that packs 8 pixels into a byte. Convert the source images to bitmaps (transparent pixel = 0 value, non-transparent = 1 value), then AND them together, then scan for non-zero values. This will be very fast - as fast as memory bandwidth. But it consumes memory for the composite image.

You could also generate an n-ary space partitioning tree for either image, with the tree nodes representing non-transparent fragments, and detect collisions by merging the trees, while including only nodes from tree 2 that overlap those of tree 1. The seminal paper [Merging BSP Trees Yields Polyhedral Set Operations](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g-fall2006/old/bsp_treemerge.pdf) gives the algorithm.

A benchmark would need to decide which is faster, and whether a hybrid approach (BSP down to a certain cell size, then bitmap representation) wouldn't be faster.